# How do I split a string at only some commas, not all?

Tags: python, csv, split

I'm pretty inexperienced at programming, and I've been doing a lot of practice problems recently. I'm currently attempting to find the sum of the x and y values of the two closest points in [this](https://d18l82el6cdm1i.cloudfront.net/uploads/documents/points-oWGbRs2l1v.txt)
set of points. The problem I'm having, is because there are commas separating the points but also in the points, I don't know how to split the string to make a list of the points

This is my code right now:

```
import csv

with open('points.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    print(header_row)
```

and the output is:

```
['{{253', ' 146}', ' {3', ' 845}', ' {-841', ' 337}', -SNIP- ' {-918', ' -736}', ' {269', ' 212}', ' {126', ' 146}}']
```

How do I change this code so it splits at only some commas, not all of them?

Comment: You might need to write a rudimentary parser to handle this.

Comment: Can you please pickout a few examples from that list to build a minimum and verifiable complete code example? This question may get closed otherwise

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060039/split-string-at-nth-occurrence-of-a-given-character

Comment: That's not a csv file so don't treat it like one.

Comment: How do you decide the commas on which you'd like to split?  What is your expected output?  And please provide the raw csv as text.

Comment: @Alexander You can see the raw "csv" in their link.

Comment: @StefanPochmann My point exactly.  There shouldn't be a link to required data.  [mcve]

Comment: `txs = tx.split(','); [','.join([a, b]) for a, b in zip(txs[::2], txs[1::2])]` gives:  `['{{253, 146}',
 ' {3, 845}',
 ' {-841, 337}',...` after the link by Astrom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data on the page is not valid Python syntax because it is listing a set of sets, which will crash in Python because sets are not hashable. However, to store the data in a similar structure, read directly from the source and replace the `{|}` with `[|]`:

```
import urllib.request as as urllib
import re
import ast
s = "https://d18l82el6cdm1i.cloudfront.net/uploads/documents/points-oWGbRs2l1v.txt"
full_data = ast.literal_eval(re.sub('}', ']', re.sub('\{', '[', [i for i in urllib.urlopen(s)][0])))
```

Output:

```
[[253, 146], [3, 845], [-841, 337], [-34, -876], [-522, -465], [-596, -570], [-917, 544], [715, 372], [573, -744], [731, -190], [133, -548], [-960, -189], [-266, -253], [-162, 954], [-293, 993], [-552, -942], [-107, 864], [-38, 257], [875, 552], [-205, -943], [1000, -491], [-353, -465], [-137, -995], [449, 175], [53, 106], [-184, -35], [-353, 450], [778, 605], [386, -466], [709, 642], [639, 193], [-749, 156], [187, -421], [-684, -968], [376, -143], [-674, 150], [-255, -667], [147, -42], [675, -163], [-275, -706], [971, -180], [660, 685], [-478, 774], [2, -45], [-12, -938], [383, -217], [119, 464], [257, -915], [149, -969], [681, -727], [-94, 404], [-708, 674], [-811, 202], [-665, -22], [898, 632], [-41, -520], [512, 828], [239, -628], [724, 698], [525, 951], [555, 145], [578, -580], [-194, -747], [-38, -735], [-735, 625], [321, 741], [-500, -988], [922, 964], [990, 25], [-667, 695], [-494, -405], [-748, -668], [-24, -444], [-589, -888], [-69, 884], [801, 77], [-142, 37], [782, 484], [-584, -411], [330, -496], [620, 888], [-65, 630], [-374, -971], [-846, -632], [179, -393], [40, -379], [-771, 229], [-38, 697], [-441, -504], [-262, 622], [-259, -13], [796, 828], [-130, -536], [-260, 430], [920, -212], [-457, -991], [-892, -510], [-115, 915], [275, 20], [761, -580], [-934, 494], [775, -486], [-202, 251], [-991, 525], [548, 338], [-139, 215], [626, -742], [-302, -6], [297, 951], [-119, -559], [711, 138], [670, 286], [83, -981], [976, -399], [-842, 468], [-310, 830], [-511, -148], [832, -556], [-316, -13], [-184, 192], [586, 377], [646, -605], [-544, 907], [-156, -340], [-426, -782], [-424, 2], [-395, -144], [-316, 760], [755, 992], [856, 86], [925, 985], [643, 273], [761, 918], [-254, 228], [631, 307], [-151, 142], [-135, -622], [-970, 593], [130, 853], [-137, -30], [-267, 547], [-838, -162], [-267, 938], [112, -849], [732, -896], [-20, -918], [-924, -95], [542, -488], [-402, 11], [-232, -162], [891, 250], [593, -429], [-713, 816], [-505, -657], [-649, -278], [801, -521], [610, -429], [-917, -324], [662, -722], [986, 561], [-835, 643], [351, -967], [-198, -239], [-457, -890], [-990, 27], [264, 965], [-143, 495], [-808, -119], [-751, -923], [-480, -159], [-669, 921], [-186, -173], [-236, -541], [-856, 609], [-159, -947], [817, 131], [-770, 561], [77, 263], [537, 64], [-635, 373], [581, 887], [-764, -12], [19, 341], [648, -551], [812, -958], [478, -511], [497, -269], [-177, -746], [155, 405], [954, -445], [-317, 971], [769, -623], [-889, -487], [-991, 837], [528, 763], [-479, -548], [-407, -398], [-187, -703], [232, -805], [-470, 508], [-734, 243], [888, -943], [665, -539], [-153, -90], [178, 686], [382, 183], [-549, 627], [-29, 948], [-204, 95], [997, -396], [457, -815], [-995, -230], [-743, 42], [-392, -514], [235, -668], [847, 195], [229, 519], [154, 483], [367, 895], [818, 625], [-988, -166], [-182, -972], [-395, -848], [-969, -421], [845, 714], [-862, -911], [-834, -550], [466, -500], [-686, 729], [-743, 703], [-310, 484], [-881, -285], [-876, -863], [-12, 800], [602, -289], [-581, -537], [-780, 775], [562, -848], [-504, 93], [670, 752], [-872, -714], [218, 358], [624, 626], [795, 246], [123, -227], [-272, 529], [-134, -840], [-443, -764], [-971, 212], [459, 388], [-562, -336], [52, 436], [-28, -124], [-431, 565], [758, -814], [875, 596], [108, 727], [-387, -785], [-144, 876], [166, 905], [964, -644], [222, 737], [322, -88], [47, -1], [310, -943], [-703, -690], [-430, 164], [-366, -328], [171, 474], [-484, -101], [-547, 920], [-666, -517], [170, -480], [-622, 232], [-24, -187], [310, -832], [-490, -193], [-774, 274], [288, 284], [-115, 982], [743, -375], [651, 625], [154, 33], [489, 9], [414, -682], [-775, 423], [-716, -442], [31, 899], [-518, -263], [509, -858], [139, 62], [154, -383], [306, 549], [726, -913], [280, -582], [-100, -183], [-975, 930], [-120, -525], [420, 844], [-286, 963], [127, 151], [-571, 534], [410, -531], [316, -692], [-624, -456], [-636, 831], [-165, 694], [857, 104], [748, -916], [468, 641], [588, 281], [455, -238], [-232, 752], [-568, -557], [120, 919], [921, 175], [944, 719], [-361, -794], [559, 741], [-689, -425], [-163, 584], [656, 906], [-383, 144], [-231, 787], [-863, 880], [649, -100], [483, -408], [440, 238], [193, 745], [-276, -373], [-620, -269], [777, -429], [-38, 920], [-205, -417], [112, -566], [977, -324], [205, -413], [-85, 491], [-101, -371], [280, 110], [90, -283], [-563, 999], [-603, -574], [148, 955], [-846, -627], [229, 31], [-145, -734], [-944, 607], [496, -759], [-275, -658], [401, -253], [210, 206], [-41, -899], [37, 589], [397, 208], [61, -117], [-189, -865], [-390, 549], [692, 678], [-14, -407], [-924, -362], [-45, 961], [718, -312], [-479, -62], [-650, -72], [499, 848], [721, -35], [-352, -658], [-203, 119], [-859, -659], [-271, -513], [478, -597], [991, 727], [-975, -244], [-200, -959], [-140, 644], [768, -740], [551, 149], [-722, 127], [-465, 375], [-510, -887], [456, 524], [-95, -230], [950, -916], [789, 53], [361, 41], [-461, 472], [951, 852], [724, -868], [443, 324], [961, -323], [-11, 108], [-961, -226], [-947, -53], [109, 875], [-372, -204], [533, -896], [-177, 217], [-862, 639], [902, -420], [414, 489], [-915, 888], [-287, 420], [-64, -436], [314, 489], [362, -648], [915, 591], [-657, 317], [899, 649], [-108, 403], [-946, 814], [368, 985], [943, 819], [-154, 172], [736, 552], [452, -607], [-43, 466], [-62, -965], [996, 970], [275, 722], [966, 164], [504, -573], [-951, 655], [47, -300], [681, -56], [108, -653], [643, -75], [-627, 336], [-960, 37], [-642, 208], [-573, -880], [478, 356], [377, 392], [-746, 683], [296, 965], [-990, 751], [-871, -368], [-783, -525], [749, 3], [-824, 673], [-644, 23], [46, 263], [517, 818], [462, -729], [-260, 40], [822, -562], [801, -443], [207, -355], [518, -403], [-160, 841], [602, -627], [-158, -188], [-960, 151], [652, 342], [379, -928], [-124, -598], [-903, 113], [-215, 980], [-544, -50], [713, 118], [-830, 694], [228, -968], [624, -327], [-138, -545], [991, 262], [777, -517], [-685, 297], [305, -67], [294, -544], [-894, -703], [-803, -617], [-958, 472], [857, -573], [-270, -501], [977, 753], [935, -478], [-118, 703], [93, 817], [645, 575], [326, -952], [-487, -956], [952, 412], [970, 775], [-506, 257], [-69, -660], [673, -559], [-48, -99], [464, -388], [-249, -839], [524, 946], [-536, -749], [964, -660], [-854, -398], [993, 523], [338, 254], [-553, 679], [253, -561], [-570, -717], [-412, 423], [699, -172], [-408, 34], [-946, -539], [-273, 66], [-545, -345], [978, 997], [868, 719], [787, 622], [159, -230], [-288, -186], [-17, 710], [153, -977], [232, -644], [876, 522], [434, 565], [-677, -481], [-609, -238], [-903, -417], [-130, -370], [-907, 737], [-466, 441], [761, -564], [893, 395], [281, 935], [434, 752], [-243, -611], [991, -254], [-756, 350], [724, -250], [-588, 827], [-32, 513], [726, 98], [372, 374], [-246, -47], [-176, 777], [-614, 0], [129, -784], [-243, 15], [846, -921], [-439, -388], [809, -937], [-241, 138], [769, -667], [-60, 951], [-5, -822], [874, -677], [-386, 304], [-555, -631], [-667, 360], [-958, -870], [-274, -266], [-928, -73], [580, 359], [-591, -696], [-775, 100], [-841, 369], [-523, 758], [-719, -981], [627, 942], [-11, -449], [-97, -776], [-204, -602], [194, -221], [335, 260], [953, 994], [124, 199], [-387, 933], [492, 291], [45, -639], [881, -795], [828, -142], [-266, 214], [310, 12], [394, 134], [190, 855], [736, -14], [696, 943], [58, -573], [-270, 327], [228, 81], [479, 630], [541, 746], [-749, 739], [-343, -78], [785, -819], [-172, 270], [-794, 613], [-437, 842], [-211, 759], [244, -127], [427, -899], [-559, -71], [970, 634], [545, 234], [-479, 64], [970, -541], [-981, -564], [909, -320], [-628, 328], [-168, 756], [893, -335], [-649, 240], [573, 989], [-833, -215], [528, -55], [761, 467], [-414, 481], [106, 181], [394, -140], [700, 110], [583, -117], [831, 62], [932, 897], [-412, 926], [859, -483], [836, 999], [205, -381], [8, 309], [-749, 795], [808, 116], [689, 287], [990, -162], [-362, -292], [716, -568], [-81, 460], [-982, -696], [-49, 790], [-532, -945], [512, 634], [-462, -615], [529, -761], [-486, -266], [-472, 586], [505, 794], [-162, -644], [-184, -152], [250, 683], [422, -755], [-773, 94], [-565, -936], [881, 109], [629, 593], [-907, -946], [-125, -416], [930, -514], [-205, 507], [327, -910], [83, -946], [-969, -521], [-457, -381], [68, -614], [510, 906], [-910, 774], [-247, 401], [-276, -578], [-81, -291], [367, 211], [-546, -718], [-167, 106], [131, 857], [542, 451], [-670, -280], [-848, -130], [-160, 472], [50, 462], [620, 428], [-46, -303], [-417, 300], [343, 974], [778, -274], [-434, -998], [-715, -379], [354, -871], [357, -203], [-227, 925], [-318, -152], [-85, -906], [-878, 881], [-672, 775], [942, -38], [10, 122], [-660, -624], [-719, 269], [-75, 267], [-30, 676], [-320, -574], [-380, 160], [-882, -515], [542, 666], [220, -719], [241, -951], [-276, -722], [416, 403], [105, 668], [-998, -254], [-259, -756], [-214, -799], [687, 722], [884, 691], [-774, 432], [224, -349], [25, -74], [-992, 386], [-824, 559], [-994, 838], [-120, 567], [732, 880], [108, 109], [-399, -675], [-181, -798], [788, 163], [74, 665], [-247, -963], [505, 160], [20, -932], [-637, 681], [765, -691], [844, -769], [-906, -698], [716, 445], [609, 221], [-617, 589], [-375, 102], [90, 294], [-484, -269], [65, -897], [-464, -505], [399, -134], [-975, 168], [912, -724], [-63, 630], [613, -476], [-95, 163], [-879, -184], [396, 25], [731, 723], [-958, -533], [-568, -643], [649, 305], [101, 353], [511, 766], [844, -406], [996, 895], [707, 398], [-790, -289], [263, 53], [867, 25], [730, 186], [396, 666], [978, 612], [944, -446], [936, 959], [310, 112], [900, -530], [959, 812], [-251, 751], [-712, 205], [208, -779], [-19, -120], [-147, -729], [508, -621], [418, -567], [164, 964], [54, 464], [518, -619], [-53, 694], [-786, -838], [-40, 845], [-235, 656], [579, -988], [485, -962], [-157, -126], [-565, -220], [-850, -336], [-865, -494], [367, 281], [261, 464], [-830, 83], [-650, -658], [-34, -757], [-351, -241], [490, -555], [93, 311], [691, 953], [-662, -5], [-908, 147], [752, -465], [-280, -292], [-296, -831], [-469, -657], [-829, -902], [57, -189], [173, 74], [-825, -67], [836, -780], [-955, -285], [945, 845], [-185, -363], [140, 654], [-115, -658], [-852, -755], [-285, 769], [603, -327], [-148, 198], [-968, 217], [-721, -954], [909, -526], [-98, -444], [-204, 914], [558, 712], [-62, -313], [614, 777], [-836, 190], [-833, 946], [-654, 706], [762, -166], [-376, -853], [-194, -841], [-682, 69], [885, -956], [36, 972], [975, -707], [-971, 720], [-528, 339], [409, 777], [-170, 480], [-50, -228], [657, 392], [378, 276], [433, -771], [36, 196], [-338, 135], [426, -114], [259, 841], [-152, 124], [616, 646], [-526, 936], [-183, -13], [817, 974], [282, 16], [-550, -935], [-559, -728], [224, 512], [-405, -124], [-212, 27], [-613, -794], [492, 318], [-308, -610], [-261, 834], [644, 308], [152, -886], [784, 999], [919, 935], [565, -807], [-951, -928], [-896, -896], [-918, 683], [-453, 14], [-396, 469], [-434, 562], [756, 990], [-486, 834], [-809, 899], [-366, 28], [970, -742], [100, -350], [-140, 817], [-567, -954], [-739, 933], [563, -107], [698, 303], [423, 72], [-162, 591], [-711, -322], [-998, 567], [768, -499], [888, -155], [502, -433], [-565, 93], [192, 589], [-854, 597], [-414, -756], [-909, 907], [-182, 777], [-638, -793], [-365, -65], [502, 532], [786, -969], [-440, 87], [981, -984], [-97, -970], [-242, -230], [577, 70], [641, 541], [209, -304], [-582, 178], [267, -175], [-952, 503], [-377, -607], [689, 160], [226, -578], [308, -703], [128, 999], [686, -468], [955, -473], [-345, -397], [-694, 347], [-606, 780], [-726, 538], [875, 559], [-904, -554], [-878, -792], [-51, -854], [361, -212], [-914, 470], [-332, 880], [-22, 361], [92, -124], [-542, 979], [363, -85], [-48, -342], [-481, -636], [635, 89], [238, 184], [-346, 437], [-398, -633], [908, -284], [-76, 92], [393, -591], [245, 657], [369, -306], [82, 436], [777, -916], [-777, 914], [200, -723], [-935, -40], [-126, -479], [924, 450], [44, 735], [692, -68], [-106, -323], [-401, 425], [272, -840], [546, 782], [-695, 57], [446, -122], [-893, -103], [241, 585], [256, 14], [-883, -508], [-896, 76], [-300, 928], [581, 290], [71, -265], [294, 110], [-136, -418], [-332, 631], [342, -574], [582, 583], [-255, -518], [-978, 781], [558, 123], [-559, -107], [-104, 546], [-751, -69], [318, 39], [110, -739], [783, -847], [-5, 989], [-429, -98], [-922, 776], [141, 152], [531, 61], [-860, -698], [-824, 725], [433, 436], [-147, 199], [882, 956], [-988, 54], [-302, -299], [566, -385], [575, -384], [-196, -250], [-479, -972], [576, 189], [-789, -470], [-114, -496], [-75, 384], [-614, -774], [598, -948], [-26, 417], [187, 185], [-878, 603], [496, -126], [530, -432], [-813, -721], [970, 667], [836, -583], [-918, -736], [269, 212], [126, 146]
```

Comment: Good analysis/idea but as usual horrific code. This time not even valid.

Comment: @StefanPochmann please see my recent edit.

Comment: Still pretty horrible, I mean, why would you use `[i for i in urllib.urlopen(s)][0]` instead of `next(urllib.urlopen(s))` or `urllib.urlopen(s).read()` and why would you use regex for this and the line is still too long to be visible at once, but at least it's no syntax error anymore and works now...

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting an error, it's saying 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlopen'

Comment: @CodingWithDan please see my recent edit. I imported the `urllib` package for Python3 under the alias of `urllib`; thus, it should work now.