# How to split a string into chunks per number of characters and delimiter?

Tags: python, string, split

Given:

```
s = 'foo, bar, baz, qudz'
```

I would like to split this string given 2 criteria:

1. a character count n (in this case, I'll use n = 10)
2. the delimiter: ", " (before the nth character)

Desired Result:

```
['foo, bar', 'baz, qudz']
```

I know I can split it by delimiter easily enough:

```
s.split(', ')
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qudz']
```

I also know that I can split it into even chunks of n like this:

```
[s[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(s), n)]
```

I've also seen where I can split by the nth delimiter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060039/split-string-at-nth-occurrence-of-a-given-character/17060409).

Comment: What do you expect with s='foo,bar,cow' and n=5?

Comment: ['foo','bar','cow']

Comment: What about in case of s='foobar,cow' and n=5?

Comment: ['foobar','cow']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `functools.reduce` to accomplish this.

```
import functools


def splitter(s, n):
    def helper(acc, v):
        tmp1 = acc[-1] 
        tmp2 = len(tmp1)
        if tmp2 >= n or tmp2 + len(v) >= n:
            acc.append(v)
        else:
            acc[-1] = tmp1 + ',' + v

        return acc

    tmp1 = s.split(',')
    if len(tmp1) == 1:
        return tmp1

    return list(functools.reduce(helper, tmp1[1:], [tmp1[0]]))
```

Comment: I was writing a recursive generator thing, but your solution's better.

Comment: This is very close, but there's just one thing: s = 'foo, bar, baz, qudz', n = 10 returns  ['foo bar', ' baz qudz'] but I need ['foo, bar', ' baz, qudz']

Comment: Changing `acc[-1] = tmp1 + v` to `acc[-1] = tmp1 + ',' + v` will address this issue (as done in the updated solution).

Comment: My man! I just split it on ', ' (with a space after the comma) instead and it works great. I wish I could give this 10 "correct answers".

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to get the substrings like so...

```
>>> re.findall(r"[\w,][\w, ]{1,8},?", "foo, bar, baz, qudz")
['foo, bar,', 'baz, qudz']
```

I find myself making edits to this after I posted. Regular expressions are tricky, but this is close to a solution if not exact. Maybe some fine tuning needed. There might be a space at the end of matches - that could be trimmed off.

Comment: If the commas count as one of the ten characters, then this here is probably the best regex: re.findall(r"\w[\w, ]{1,8}(?:,|\w$)", "foo, bar, baz, qudz")   It assumes that we don't want the substring starting character to be a comma.